# ggtern - fill/smooth area between values of triangulation points

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtern

I am using ggtern and want to create a plot where the area between points of the triangle is filled/smoothed based on point values at each triangulation point. Something like below...
[target plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udw1M.png)

But what I get so far is...
[current state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jjh5c.png)

Below some data and code example.

**Thank you for your help!**

```
a <- c(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.9, 0.9, 0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.8, 0.3, 0.7, 0.0, 0.0, 0.3, 0.7, 0.0, 0.4, 0.0, 0.6, 0.6, 0.4, 0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.7, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.7,
    0.2, 0.6, 0.1, 0.1, 0.6, 0.3, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.4, 0.6, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4)
b <- c(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.1, 0.9, 0.0, 0.1, 0.9, 0.0, 0.0, 0.8, 0.2, 0.8, 0.0, 0.2, 0.0, 0.3, 0.7, 0.3, 0.7, 0.0, 0.6, 0.0, 0.4, 0.0, 0.4, 0.6, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.7, 0.7, 0.2,
     0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 0.3, 0.6, 0.1, 0.4, 0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.2, 0.6, 0.2, 0.5, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3)
c <- c(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.9, 0.1, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.9, 0.2, 0.2, 0.8, 0.0, 0.8, 0.0, 0.7, 0.0, 0.3, 0.7, 0.0, 0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 0.6, 0.4, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.8, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.7, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1,
     0.7, 0.3, 0.6, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 0.3)
value <- c(1.433, 0.251, 0.000, 0.176, 0.000, 1.556, 1.490, 0.087, 0.522, 1.718, 0.000, 0.098, 0.347, 0.772, 1.642, 1.093, 1.762, 0.000, 0.052, 0.713, 1.857, 0.000, 1.367, 0.022, 1.814,
       1.726, 1.043, 1.424, 0.001, 1.722, 0.428, 0.122, 1.656, 1.798, 0.330, 0.384, 0.138, 1.777, 0.661, 1.763, 0.271, 0.166, 1.733, 0.753, 0.984, 0.236, 1.574, 0.204, 1.232, 1.471,
       1.086, 1.748, 0.409, 0.568, 0.790, 1.505, 0.520, 1.552, 0.451, 0.884, 1.094, 1.180, 0.484, 0.831, 0.859, 1.123)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c,value)

library(ggtern)
ggtern(df,aes(a, b, c)) +
geom_point(size=2, aes(color=value)) +
theme_rgbw()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying the example in the `ggtern` package documentation you could try this. You'll probably have to experiment with the inputs and arguments to get the result you require, but this should provide a start.
Edited arguments to make more like OP request for distinct fill areas and remove points, and grid ontop, now.

```r
library(ggtern)
ggtern(df, aes(a, b, c, value = value)) +
  stat_interpolate_tern(geom="polygon",
                        formula = value~y+x,
                        method = lm,
                        n = 100,
                        breaks = seq(0, 2.5, length.out = 8),
                        aes(fill = ..level..),
                        expand = 1) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "red")+
  theme_rgbw()+
  theme(tern.panel.grid.ontop = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Dear Peter, thanks for your answer and suggestion! I was looking more for a way similar in the example, where the filled area could also be segmented :-/ Is there maybe an alternative package then ggtern that does the trick?

Comment: A kind of ternary contour diagram?

Comment: Thank you a lot! At leas this is coming close. Is it also possible to put the grid on top ?