# ggtern - create contoured ternary plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, ternary, ggtern

I am trying to create a ternary plot with contoured filling using the "ggtern" package. The aim would be to create a similar plot as shown below, where each triangulation point (EXT;INT;SA) expresses a value MF...

[image]

I was using the "stat_interpolate_tern()" function, based on the friendly support of the stackoverflow community [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69191949/ggtern-fill-smooth-area-between-values-of-triangulation-points). However, due to the linear model of the interpolation, the decreasing values in the right bottom corner are then missing. Also defining the contour thresholds is not optimal. What I get so far...

[image]

Does anyone have an idea, how this can be done with ggtern? Here the data and code example...

```
SA <- c(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.9, 0.9, 0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.8, 0.3, 0.7, 0.0, 0.0, 0.3, 0.7, 0.0, 0.4, 0.0, 0.6, 0.6, 0.4, 0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.7, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.7,
    0.2, 0.6, 0.1, 0.1, 0.6, 0.3, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.4, 0.6, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4)
INT <- c(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.1, 0.9, 0.0, 0.1, 0.9, 0.0, 0.0, 0.8, 0.2, 0.8, 0.0, 0.2, 0.0, 0.3, 0.7, 0.3, 0.7, 0.0, 0.6, 0.0, 0.4, 0.0, 0.4, 0.6, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.7, 0.7, 0.2,
     0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 0.3, 0.6, 0.1, 0.4, 0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.2, 0.6, 0.2, 0.5, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3)
EXT <- c(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.9, 0.1, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.9, 0.2, 0.2, 0.8, 0.0, 0.8, 0.0, 0.7, 0.0, 0.3, 0.7, 0.0, 0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 0.6, 0.4, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.8, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.7, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1,
     0.7, 0.3, 0.6, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 0.3)
MF <- c(1.433, 0.251, 0.000, 0.176, 0.000, 1.556, 1.490, 0.087, 0.522, 1.718, 0.000, 0.098, 0.347, 0.772, 1.642, 1.093, 1.762, 0.000, 0.052, 0.713, 1.857, 0.000, 1.367, 0.022, 1.814,
       1.726, 1.043, 1.424, 0.001, 1.722, 0.428, 0.122, 1.656, 1.798, 0.330, 0.384, 0.138, 1.777, 0.661, 1.763, 0.271, 0.166, 1.733, 0.753, 0.984, 0.236, 1.574, 0.204, 1.232, 1.471,
       1.086, 1.748, 0.409, 0.568, 0.790, 1.505, 0.520, 1.552, 0.451, 0.884, 1.094, 1.180, 0.484, 0.831, 0.859, 1.123)
df <- data.frame(SA,INT,EXT,MF)

library(ggtern)
library(viridis)

ggtern(df, aes(INT, EXT,SA, value = MF)) +
  stat_interpolate_tern(geom="polygon",
                        formula = value~y+x,
                        method = lm, n = 100,
                        breaks = seq(0, 2.5, length.out = 9),
                        aes(fill = ..level..), expand = 1) +
  scale_fill_viridis()+
  labs(fill = "MultiF.") +
  theme_rgbw() +
  theme(tern.panel.grid.ontop = TRUE)
```

**Thank you in advance for your support!**

Answer (score 1):

With ggtern, I had some difficulties as well providing the right interpolation. Especially, the polygons are a bit tricky.

When you switch to `stat = "InterpolateTern"` instead of `stat = "polygon"`, you could reproduce your example, together with the important changes in `base = "identity"` and `method = "auto"`:

```
ggtern(df,
  aes(INT, EXT,SA, value = MF)) +
    geom_interpolate_tern(
        stat = "InterpolateTern",
        method = "auto",
        na.rm = TRUE,
        formula = value ~ x + y,
        expand = 0,
        base = "identity",
        aes(
            colour = after_stat(level)
        ),
        breaks = seq(0,1.75, length.out = 9),
        size = 2
    ) + scale_colour_viridis() +
    theme_rgbw()
```

But this gives only the countours:

[image]

I was not able to generate a polygon based plot to deliver the desired output as the polygons are usually truncated.

[image]

I helped myself with a workaround:

```
ggtern(df, 
             aes(INT, EXT,SA, value = MF)) +
    geom_interpolate_tern(
        stat = "InterpolateTern",
        method = "auto",
        na.rm = TRUE,
        formula = value ~ x + y,
        expand = 0,
        base = "identity",
        aes(
            colour = after_stat(level)
        ),
        breaks = seq(0,1.8, length.out = 500),
        size = 5
    ) +
    geom_interpolate_tern(
        stat = "InterpolateTern",
        method = "auto",
        na.rm = TRUE,
        formula = value ~ x + y,
        expand = 0,
        base = "identity",
        aes(
            colour = after_stat(level)
        ),
        breaks = seq(0, 1.75, length.out = 9),
        size = 1,
        colour = "white"
    )+  scale_colour_viridis() +
    theme_rgbw() + 
    theme_gridsontop()
```

This delivers:

[image]

You have to play a bit with `breaks` and `size` to colour the whole area. Probably, it is worth to calculate a model first and plot this extrapolated to the triangle corners.

Another alternative:

```
ggtern(df, 
             aes(INT, EXT,SA, value = MF)) +
    geom_hex_tern(
        stat = "hex_tern",
        fun = "mean",
        na.rm = TRUE,
        binwidth = .1 # depends on your data granularity  
    ) +
    scale_fill_viridis() +
    theme_rgbw() + 
    theme_gridsontop()
```

Resulting in:

[image]

Kind regards
Markus

Comment: Dear Markus, thanks a lot for your help! The variant with the hexagons is great!